# How do I save a proberty on an object in AngularFire without erasing other properties?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

All I want to do is essentially replace the username on my credentials path under the user but when I run the following code it is erasing all the other data on the credentials path(object) even though I am explicitly just rewriting one property. How do I update an object in AngularFire, I know I can do it without AngularFire using `.set` but I want to return a promise. Here is my code:

```
editCredentials: function(uid, credItem, newData){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/' + uid + '/credentials/');
    var editCred = $firebaseObject(ref);
    editCred[credItem] = newData;
    editCred.$save(ref)
      .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just update the node instead of re-writing it?

Comment: Cross-post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/40nwgu/how_do_i_properly_addupdatesave_data_to_a/

Answer (score -1):

AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. That means that you don't *have* to use AngularFire for operations that are easier to do with the regular JavaScript SDK.

In this case:

```
editCredentials: function(uid, credItem, newData){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/' + uid + '/credentials/');
    ref.update({ 'credItem': newData });
}
```